# Using Org-Mode With the Gnome 3 Calendar

Tags: org-mode, gnome-3

Gnome 3 has [a beautiful calendar panel](http://davidz25.blogspot.com/2011/01/gnome-3-calendar.html) that drops down from the menu bar, and includes a space for your upcoming appointments.  By default this appointment manager reads from the calendar in Evolution Mail.  I was curious as to whether it's possible to get it working with Org-Mode.  I know Evolution can import .ics files and Org-Mode can write them, so that's a start.  Does anyone have thoughts as to how you might (a) get the Gnome 3 Calendar working directly with Org-Mode, or (b) set up an efficient sync between Org-Mode and Evolution Mail's calendar, such that it would be reflected in the Gnome 3 Calendar panel?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for: I send my org-agenda to appt. Appt then uses notify-send to tell system about appointments. Which show up in appointment manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you already use the `org-agenda`. What you are looking for is `org-write-agenda` to get the exported ics file. I'd wrap that function with your own custom `sync-cal` function. `sync-call` should go ahead write the agenda `/tmp` and then you should issue some shell commands (see `start-process`) to sync with Evolution (how to do that, I do not know). Now, you maybe want to hook your `sync-cal` function to some [file save functions](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Buffers.html#Saving-Buffers) and run it depending on the file name.

Hacky, but that's how I'd do it if I'd use Gnome.

Comment: That's a good start, thanks.  I'll mess with it some when I get the opportunity and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @JoshBraun Triggering the import to Evolution will probably be the most difficult thing, in accordance with Gnome guidelines. I'd try that first. Also, make sure to read the SO FAQ and accustom yourself with voting and accepting answers.

Comment: Will do on all counts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An idea that occurred to me later in the day—a bit circuitous, but possible—is to go through Google Calendar.  There are [existing Org-Mode scripts for writing to Google Calendar](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html), and a standard [procedure in Evolution Mail for reading from Google Calendar](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8226-how-to-sync-evolution-with-googles-pim-apps).  So if you don't mind going through a third party or having calendar updates depend on Internet access, it should be possible to sync through Google.  It's not an elegant solution, but it's at least well documented.

Answer (score 0):

For synchronisation between Evolution and a dedicated org file (one-way only, for now), here's a Python script: [org-agenda-evolution](https://github.com/creichen/org-agenda-evolution).

(Disclaimer: (1) I am the author, (2) as of 2022-08, the tool lacks a configuration system, so right now you may have to tweak some top-level constants in the source to make it work for your org-mode setup.)